# What is the term for the lines that let you resize dialogs?

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a term for these 'lines' that often appear on the bottom right corner in dialogs. Is there an official term for this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @Gerlof Leuhof, You will get better answers at https://ux.stackexchange.com/ where there are people with more experience in these topic

Comment: @Danielillo I disagree. The fact that it would be a *better* fit on UX does not mean that it would be off-topic here. Imho, this is something that graphic designers could know, and is relevant to their job, as they might have to design and talk about these objects.

Comment: @Vincent Sometimes it is too broad what is in and what is out. In these cases I tend to see the practical side, and in the other site there are more people working with this type of things daily, so as far as the name is concerned, it seemed more appropriate to insert it there (to me). Different would be that the question faced about the design possibilities of this object. Anyway, the OP got a good answer here.

Comment: I totally see where you're coming from @Danielillo. I'm also a bit avaricious about pushing away a question that would fit nicely on this site, creating content and traffic here. We want to keep this site in good shape :)

Comment: @Vincent Good shape and good quality or just good shape? 

Comment: @Danielillo Both. I think this Q is not detrimental to our quality at all, do you? :)

Comment: @Vincent Not at all, as you already know I'm against the easy closing, that's why I use to add a little explanation everytime  I suggest to close a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have always called it a "resizing handle".

It might not be an official name though. According to [an online computer jargon dictionary](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/sizehand.htm) it can also be called "sizing handle", "handle", "drag handle", "sizing grip" or "resize corner".

Comment: I'm getting a lot of hits on Google on 'Resize handle'. Thanks!